# Register model from pipeline (CLI v2)

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I have a pipeline where I do training for a model and at the end I'd like to register that model but I can't find any information on this.

Here's how my pipeline looks now:

```yaml
type: pipeline_job

compute:
  target: azureml:gpu-cluster

inputs:
  input_images:
    data:
      datastore: azureml:dualcam
      path: /image-20210701*

jobs:
  training:
    type: component_job
    component: file:./components/training.yml
    inputs:
      input_images: inputs.input_images
```

Answer (score 1):

You can upload it to the run using upload_file and then register the model.

Uploading the model into the run history record before trying to register the model:

```
run.upload_file("outputs/my_model.pickle", "outputs/my_model.pickle")
print(run.get_file_names())
print(os.getcwd())
model = run.register_model(model_name='simtemp', model_path="outputs/{}".format(model_file_name))
```

Please follow the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.run.run?view=azure-ml-py#upload-file-name--path-or-stream-) for run.

Comment: Thank you however I'm not using the Python SDK

Comment: To train models with the CLI v2.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-train-cli

Comment: Do they register the model? I can't find it.